# How do you have a different texture material for the interior sides of an object than exterior?

Tags: texturing, normals, texture-baking

So I made a bus. The exterior of the bus has a texture material. The purple mesh "body" shows up in game. But the interior is all transparent.

Now the way to bake/uv map interiors is by flipping normals. But what is the exact process to splitting the bakes in the object hierarchy or organizing them in the pane in the right most object window/material window ?

[image]